# Known distributions that generate sparse vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have data that comes in the form of a vector. Each vector is sparse. Is there a commonly used distribution that will generate sparse vectors?

I am working on a project where I am passing a bunch of dog images through a convolutional neural network(CNN) and trying to model a joint distribution of the activations at a specific layer. The activations are turning out to be sparse because the CNN is using RELU activation functions. As a result the the vector is sparse(has lots of zeros) and the nonzeros values can take on any value above zero.

Comment: Probably lots of such distributions.  Please edit the question to tell us more about your vector, and specifically about the non-zero values.  Is it a 0/1 vector?  A real-valued vector?  Also how is this a computer science question rather than a Stats.SE or Math.SE question?  While we're not 100% averse to pure math questions, we expect the question to articulate the connection to CS and explain why it needs to be answered from a CS perspective or by a computer scientist.

Comment: If you fully specified your statistical model then perhaps more users would be able to help.